# Roughly removing 'duplicate' photos based on filename

Tags: python

I quickly wanted a script that'll go through a lot of photos in a folder and only keep one photo per minute (gotta love burst shots on iPhone).

Fortunately, Dropbox names them with a timestamp upon import: I was thus allowed to base this one on the filename (an example filename is '2013-11-06 23.32.19 XXXXXX.jpg').

I was thinking of maybe moving these files to a 'duplicate' folder or something, just didn't have the time to figure it out for now. I only just started Python, and it was definitely fun to have such a tiny assignment done in under 10 minutes :)

Any comments on how I could've done this in a more pretty way is appreciated!

```
import os
directory = "{pathToPhotos}"

dt_counter = {}
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if not filename.endswith('.ini'):
        dt_rounded = filename[:16]
        if dt_rounded in dt_counter.keys():
            dt_counter[dt_rounded] += 1
        else:
            dt_counter[dt_rounded] = 1
        if dt_counter[dt_rounded] > 1:
            os.remove(os.path.join(directory, filename))
```

Additionally, I was thinking of expanding this due to the many 'duplicate' photos I have (same setting, different photo's) by grouping them in 10 second buckets and creating a GUI or so to show all alternatives and choose one to keep, any tips on where to start with this would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FWIW, using `pathlib` makes the code a little nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only dealing with only `.jpg` files then it will be better to use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module:

```
import glob

for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory), '*.jpg'):
   ...
```

Don't use `dict.keys()` to check for the existence of a key in dictionary, it is inefficient in Python 2(created a whole list first and then searches for key in that list) and requires an unnecessary call to `.keys()` in Python 3. Or even better use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to keep counts of objects:

```
from collections import Counter

dt_counter = Counter()

for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory), '*.jpg'):
    dt_rounded = os.path.split(filepath)[1][:16]
    dt_counter[dt_rounded] += 1
    if dt_counter[dt_rounded] > 1:
         # if `directory` is actually a `pathToPhotos` then you 
         # don't need to call os.path.join anymore
         os.remove(filepath)
```